# PyCord Discord Bot Two Parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, pycord

I am trying to have a slash command that takes two parameters at least, for some reason it is not working and I can not find any documentation about.

```
@bot.slash_command(name='greet', description='Greet someone!')
@discord.option(
    "name",
    description="Enter Name in format: John Doe",
    required=False,
    default='John Doe'
)
@discord.option(
    "collar",
    description="Enter Collar number e.g. 1789",
    required=False,
    default='1123'
)
async def greet(
    ctx: discord.ApplicationContext,
    name: str,
    collar: str
):
    await ctx.send(f'{name} {collar} \n' "http://imgur.com/gallery/YiMUiop")


bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN')) # run the bot with the token
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about the problem you're facing? Like the options not showing up, the options are not working as expected, etc. So people can understand the situation better.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use with PyCord v2.3

```py
from discord import Option

@bot.slash_command(description = "Greet someone!")
async def greet(ctx, 
               name:Option(str,
                           description="Enter Name in format: John Doe",
                           required=False,
                           default='John Doe'),
               collar: Option(str,
                              description="Enter Collar number e.g. 1789",
                              required=False,
                              default='1123'
                             )
              ):
  await ctx.respond(f'{name} {collar} \n' "http://imgur.com/gallery/YiMUiop")


bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN')) # run the bot with the token
```

Comment: Also, here's the link to PyCord docs: https://guide.pycord.dev/interactions/application-commands/slash-commands